# How to compare 2 SQL table for difference

Tags: sql, distinct, except

given the following table, how can I have the difference between the 2 tables giving the fact that T143 has every rows duplicated:

```
T001.CODE             T143.CODE
----                   -----
A1                     A1
                       A1
A2                     A2
                       A2
A3             

A4                     A4
                       A4
```

Result should be A3 as its only present in T001 - I also need to display all column from T143.

Here's what I have do far but after a manual check of data there is mistake:

```
SELECT CODE FROM T001 
EXCEPT 
SELECT CODE FROM T143
```

thanks

Comment: can you show the result you're currently getting?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: If you result is supposed to be A3, your query as is seems to be working both under PostgreSQL and SQLite3.

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do this using `exists`:

```
select t1.code
from t001 t1
where not exists (select 1 from t143 t2 where t2.code = t1.code);
```

If you also want the columns from `t2`, then use `union all` to get them.

If you want *all* codes in both tables, just do:

```
select t1.code
from t001
union  -- on purpose for duplicate removal
select t2.code
from t143;
```

Comment: He  'also needs to display all column from T143.'

Answer (score 0):

A Full outer join should do the trick

```
SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(T001.CODE,T143.CODE), T143.*
FROM T001 FULL OUTER JOIN T143 
 ON T001.CODE = T143.CODE 
WHERE T001.CODE IS NULL OR T143.CODE IS NULL
```

EDIT: Since DISTINCT is mentioned in the tags, i added it to the query

Comment: seems to be working, I used T001.* instead of T143.* in order to display all column - does it make sence?